# Grails: Convert int to enum in JSON unmarshalling

Tags: json, grails, groovy, enums

I'm using HttpBuilder to call a REST service. I need to convert JSON response into a POGO.

Here a simplified REST call:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://www.example.com/api')
http.request(Method.POST, ContentType.JSON) {
    /* ... */
    response.success { resp, json ->
        MyPogo pogo = (MyPogo) json
    }
}
```

It usually works.

But now I hava a JSON like this:

```
{ persons: [{ name:"Jhon", gender:0 }, { name:"Mary", gender:1 }] }
```

And MyPogo has a Gendern enum, like this:

```
class MyPogo implements Serializable {
    String name
    Gender gender
}

enum Gender {
    MALE(0),
    FEMALE(1)

    private final int key

    Gender(int key) { this.key = key }
}
```

Using this POGO, HttpBuilder throws a GrailsCastException (cannot cast Integer to Gender).

I know how convert an int to an enum and how to register a custom JSON marshaller, but how can I register a custom unmarshaller only for Gender enum?

**EDIT**: Type definition in enum constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add type definition in constructor:

```
enum Gender {
    MALE(0),
    FEMALE(1)

    private final int key

    Gender(int key) { 
        this.key = key 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry: I write bad my example. My real code is already like you suggest :(